# I need a Google Sheets script & formula regarding looking up a dynamic value from a range of cells and using that value in a formula elsewhere?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to have a script that runs upon change in values to the sheet. What I have setup on my sheet is a few cells in a column that can have dynamic values typed into one of them (ex. J6:J10). I would like the script to run and check for a dynamic value in one of the cells, which it would then use that value in a formula contained in a different cell (I6) to calculate a formula similar to this: =ROUND(**J6**/E6,2). Cell J6 being dynamic.

I need the formula to be dynamic to match whichever **J** cell row has data and correlate to the **E** cell row

I was only able to get the sheet setup with its basic layout. I am still missing a working script that functions with the proper dynamic formula

Comment: There are no triggers that fire on change due to formulas or other scripts

Comment: It's not quite clear your goal. You need the formula in I6 to find the first value in J column?

Comment: @Martín Here is a screenshot of my sheet. I need to be able to run a script that detects when cell I4 changes based on what value is typed into any cell within J6:J10. That value that is populated in I4 will subsequently change the values in I6:10. I hope that is clearer https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBucA.png

Answer (score 0):

If only 1 of the cells in `J6:J10` has the value which you want to work with you could use in `I6`:

```
=ROUND(SUM(J6:J10)/E6,2)
```

Comment: That would work if only one value is added, which is essentially what I want. It would break the formula result if more than one was added. Hopefully the others using this will listen to directions. Not sure if there would be a formula to take the lowest ratio from those numbers (excluding zero) and use it as a safeguard in case more than one number was used. The other issue that I am seeing is that the **E** row in the formula needs to be dynamic based on what row (ex J8) contains the data entered

Comment: If you want to prevent a zero division error, you can wrap the whole formula in the iferror function. And what do you mean by lowest ratio?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It calculates all the ratios, and FILTER if J is empty; and finds the minimum ratio with MIN:

```
=IFNA(MIN(FILTER(INDEX(J6:10/E6:E10),J6:J10<>"")))
```

Comment: Obviously you can wrap it in Round to the decimals

Comment: following up on your solution, I have another issue I am trying to solve. How would I be able to compare a dynamic value provided from another sheet in cell F14 to a dynamic user provided value in cell E14 and take the lowest value, to then be used in the formula contained in cell D8  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnHUA.png